# How to send Server-Sent Event Notifications when needed, not periodically, to a specific browser session?

Tags: html, server-sent-events

I want to use SSE's to send data from the server to ***a specific individual*** client that is logged in to my web-application, when their session timeout 'clock' is about to expire or when there is a message that is supposed to be sent to all 'connected' users, similar to a UNIX wall command, such as 'the system will be unavailable in 5 minute, please complete your transactions and log-off.'

The examples that I've seen at w3schools and MSDN, automatically/periodically send messages to the connected clients, such as transmitting the server's time.

I want to avoid polling the server from the client with ajax requests for questions like 'Am I still logged-in?' (session timeout expired) or 'What, if any, is the the server message?'  The first is specific to the user and the second is for all current users.

Can this be done, and is there an example of how to do this?

Thanks

Since posting this question, I was partially successful in cobbling a SSE server/client demo to work.  I say, partly successful, because I've not been able to get the different durations to work using the retry option.  If I leave the option out, the client gets a message every three seconds.  If I include the option, then the client only gets one message and hages trying to connect with the server.  Here is the PHP server-side code:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/event-stream' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );

// data: {"msg": "First message"}\ndata: {"msg": "second message"}\n\n

$r  = mt_rand( 1, 10 ) * 1000;
$m  = "retry interval: ${r}";
$r *= 1000;
$t = date( 'r' );

// echo "retry: ${r}" . PHP_EOL; // <==== With out this, it works!

echo "data: {\"message\" : \"${m}\"}" . PHP_EOL;
echo "data: {\"message\" : \"The server time is: ${t}\"}" .  PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Here is the client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Server-Sent Events Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
     <button onclick="source.close();">Stop!</button>
    </p>
    <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>

      // Source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

      if( typeof( EventSource ) !== 'undefined' ) {

        // 'http://symfony.dev.iambreakinout.com/SSE_Server.php'

        var source = new EventSource( 'SSE_Server.php' );

        source.addEventListener(
          'message',
          function( event ) {
            if( event.origin != window.location.origin ) {    
              alert( 'Cross-site scripting: message origin did not match:' +
                     '\r\n' +
                     'expected origin: ' + window.location.origin + '\r\n' +
                     'actual origin:  ' + event.origin );

              return;

            }
            else {
              var data = [];

              for( var i = 0, b = 0, e = 0, d = '';; ++i, b = e + 1 ) {

                e         = event.data.indexOf( "\n", b );
                s         = ( ( e > -1 )
                              ? event.data.substr( b, e )
                              : event.data.substr( b ) );
                data[ i ] = JSON.parse( s ).message;

                if( e === -1 ) break;

              }

              document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML +=
                data.join( '<br>' ) + '<br>';

            }

          },
          false );

        source.addEventListener(
          'open',
          function( event ) {
            // Connection was opened.

            document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML += 'Open<br>';
          },
          false );

        source.addEventListener(
          'error',
          function( event ) {
            var readyState;

            //
            // The closed ready state is seen when an error event occurs, but
            // the rest are shown here as a reminder to me of the defined
            // ready state constant values.
            //

            switch( event.currentTarget.readyState ) {
              case EventSource.CONNECTING: readyState = 'Connecting'; break;
              case EventSource.OPEN:       readyState = 'Open';       break;
              case EventSource.CLOSED:     readyState = 'Closed';     break;
              default:                     readyState = '?';          break;
            }
            document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML += readyState +
              '<br>';

          },
          false );

      }
      else {

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
          'Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...';

      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="source.close();">Stop!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Without changing the client code and allowing the **echo "retry: ${r}" . PHP_EOL;** statement to specify a retry duration causes the output to stop after **Connecting** i shown.

## Getting server updates

Open

retry interval: 3000

Connecting

What am I doing wrong or not doing to allow for the retry option to work?

Thanks again

OK, the code as stands is fine, but it really should not have had the first 'times 1000' when it generated the random number of interval. (duh!).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your active users in some data structure to be able to send events to them.

Below is a simple commented example on NodeJS (based on https://github.com/mchaov/simple-sse-nodejs-setup/):

```
const http = require('http');
const msg = " - Simple SSE server - ";
const port = 5000;

// Create basic server
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    // answer only to event stream requests
    if (request.headers.accept && request.headers.accept == 'text/event-stream') {

        // check if the resource is what we want
        // => http://domain.ext/sse
        // store the user into your data structure
        if (/sse/gim.test(request.url)) {
            sendSSE(request, response);
        }
    }
    else {
        // if not just return that you are online and a string of text
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.write('Welcome to ' + msg + '@ :' + port);
        response.end();
    }
}).listen(port);

// Setup the SSE "service" :)
// You need to cache the "response" object per user, and then you can use the functions below to send messages whenever you desire. You can have a collection that holds all the references to the response object and decide if you want to send message to one or all.
function sendSSE(request, response) {

    // Setup headers
    // For ease of use: example for enabled CORS
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',

        // enabling CORS
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    });

    var id = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

    // send first message
    constructSSE(response, id, (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());

    // send message every second and a half
    setInterval(function () {
        constructSSE(response, id, (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());
    }, 1500);
}

// setup simple message
// call this function with proper response you took from data structure with active users to send message to the specific user
function constructSSE(response, id, data) {
    response.write('id: ' + id + '\n');
    // response.write('event: ' + 'logout' + '\n'); // check this
    response.write("data: " + msg + port + '\n\n');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  The purpose of this is be added to my PHP/Symfony 2 web-app, which produces HTML and JavaScript with JQuery and BootStrap output to the user's browser.  I hesitate to try using NodesJS in the mix.

Comment: Well, I don't know PHP, but the premise stays the same. You need some class to manage your active users.

Comment: Again. thanks.  I'm sorry, but I don't see how your example sends the logout message to  a specific user.  Was that the intent or was it a message to all users telling them to logout>

Comment: I intended to give you a function you can call to send message to specific user. You have that in the code above. I don't intent do write your server for you. I gave you general guidance to achieve your goal by storing the response objects in a hashtable with some key that helps you identify the user. Then it is simple as ```sendMessage(hash[userID], message)``` The ```hash[userID]``` will point you to the correct response object so you could send the message. If you need the entire solution, consider putting bounty or hiring someone to do it.